# How to react to facebook post with facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im working to set up auto react to facebook with graph api but its not working.

This is code so far

```html
if($result){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
$m = $row['token'];
$facebook->setAccessToken ($m);
$id =$_POST['id'];
try {

$react = array("WOW");


$facebook->api("/v2.8/".$id."/reactions", 'POST', array('type' => $react));
$msg1 = "<font color='get'>Success!</font>";
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
$output .= "<p>'". $row['name'] . "' failed to like.</p>";
$msg2 = "<font color='red'>Failed to Like!</font>";
}
}
}
mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

What is going wrong, can someone tell me ?

Comment: "not working" is not a sufficient error description. please debug your code and be more specific. (debug info, errors, ...)

Comment: I don't know how to debug

Comment: What do you mean by “auto react”? You are not allowed to have bots/scripts react to stuff “automatically.”

Comment: if you don´t know how to debug, learn that first. and THEN start to deal with the facebook api. also, what cbroe said.

Answer (score 0):

This site http://robotliker.net is using reaction and autolike but with script below i don.t know what is wrong